# Sublime Text 2 - Project TODO Plugin?

Tags: macos, plugins, text-editors

In editors like netbeans there is a window to view all comments that start with `#TODO:`

Is there a plugin for Sublime Text to view all `#TODO:` comments throughout the whole project in a single window?

Right now I am just using <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and it works pretty well. Just wondering if there was a more permanent plugin.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm working on one right now. It uses [pss](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pss), a python ack clone, to search current open folders for known tags like TODO and FIXME. Find it [here](https://github.com/robcowie/SublimeTODO).

Output will be similar to that of the Textmate TODO bundle.

Right now it's a little rough around the edges, with at least one reproducible failure, but you are of course welcome to give it a go. When it is at a stable point, I'll make it available via the Sublime package manager

**UPDATE:** For the sake of anyone still looking for such a plugin, this plugin is now stable and installable via the sublime package manager under the name SublimeTODO.

Comment: Comment at the top of this repo: [DEPRECATED] - See https://github.com/jonathandelgado/SublimeTodoReview - Extract TODO-type comments from open files and project folders